# telephone introducing myself (not name)

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-usage, word-in-context

Good morning, when we do a call, usually we introduce ourselves or answer using "this is Name" or "it's Name". But if I should say that I am the father/friend/colleuge/mother etc of the person who the caller is looking for, can I use: "I am a/the...", right? And why not "this is etc..." thanks
Here I found an example https://books.google.it/books?id=Kh_RZhvHk0YC&pg=PT128&dq=%22i%27m+a+friend+of%22+telephone+dialogue&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT-PXf_LrhAhVMKlAKHWaMCjEQ6AEIEjAB#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20a%20friend%20of%22%20telephone%20dialogue&f=false

Comment: I thought "this is Peter's father" seems OK if Peter's phone happens to be in his fathers hand.

Comment: I found online just: "I am name's father"... Or better many many examples with "a friend of..."

Comment: I am keeping on looking for and more I see more I am sure that it's right to say I am... But I do not why... Uff

Comment: Either form of the expression can be used.

Comment: Really? Also with "it's"? Is there any difference with  I am"?

Comment: Which one is the most used?